# Global differential form arising from an hermitian line bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, riemann-surfaces, line-bundles

Let $X$ be a compact, connected Riemann surface and let $(L,h)$ be an hermitian line bundle on $X$. Suppose that $s$ is a nonzero meromorphic section of $L$. I've learned that the $(1,1)$-form 
$$\omega_s:=\partial\bar\partial \log (h(s,s))$$
is very important for the study of the geometry of $X$, but there are a couple of things that I don't understand:

> 1. Why is $\omega_s$ defined on the whole $X$? I mean, $h(s,s)$ is well defined only out from the poles and the zeroes of $s$. Let's
>      denote this open set with $U$, then $\omega_s$ is a $(1,1)$-form on
>      $U$ and there should be a way to extend it uniquely to $X$.
> 2. Assuming that $1.$ is proved, I want to understand why if $t$ is another meromorphic section of $L$, then $\omega_s=\omega_t$.

Could you please give a proof of these facts?

**Edit:** Clearly by $h$ I mean a smooth collection of hermitian products $h_x$ on the complex vector spaces $L_x$, for $x\in X$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$By removing the zeros and poles as you describe, you can (and should) think of $s$ as a non-vanishing local holomorphic section. Since $L$ is locally trivial on $X$, there exists a non-vanishing local holomorphic section in a neighborhood of an arbitrary point of $X$.

If $t$ is another, the ratio $s/t := f$ is a non-vanishing local holomorphic function, and
\begin{align*}
  \omega_{s} &= -i\dd \bar{\dd} \log h(s, s) \\
  &= -i\dd \bar{\dd} \log h(ft, ft) \\
  &= -i\dd \bar{\dd} \log \bigl[f\bar{f}\, h(t, t)\bigr] \\
  &= -i\dd \bar{\dd} \bigl[\log f + \log \bar{f} + \log h(t, t)\bigr] \\
  &= -i\dd \bar{\dd} \log h(t, t)
\end{align*}
since $\log f$ is holomorphic (hence annihilated by $\bar{\dd}$) and $\log \bar{f}$ is antiholomorphic (annihilated by $\dd$).

Comment: Moreover by the local triviality of $ L$ $\omega_s$ can be extended to the whole $X$. Right?

Comment: Also, this form is equal to the curvature form of $(L,h) $, thus defined on the whole manifold.

Comment: As manifold and Gunnar note, there is a global $(1, 1)$-form, the _curvature form_ of the Hermitian structure $h$, given locally by $-i\dd\bar{\dd} \log h(\cdot, \cdot)$. This form represents $2\pi\, c_{1}(L)$, and may be viewed as the curvature of the principal circle bundle over $X$ consisting of $h$-unit vectors.